# Table td colspan not working for tr with ids

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html-table

I have a table structure similar to below:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="5">
    TEST
  </td>
</tr>
<tr id="abcd_<?php echo  $id; ?>" style="display: none;">
  <td colspan="5">
    <span id="hidtb_<?php echo  $id; ?>"></span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The table is within a loop and the value of `$id` changes. The second `tr` is set to `display : block` using javascript. But the  `<td colspan="5">` is not covering all the five `<td>`s, instead only one.

Why my `colspan` is not working?

[image: final output table]

Comment: HTML seems correct. It should work.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi: it will not work, see my answer below...

Comment: @Legionar: nice answer. but i am afraid it support all browsers?

Comment: @SureshKamrushi: at least in firefox and safari there will be problem with `display: block` for `tr`.

Comment: How is this related to Javascript or AJAX? Does this work if you use fixed markup? Then this would neither be related to PHP after all

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is the problem with `display: block`.

Please refer the below link
http://thedesignspace.net/MT2archives/000376.html#.UUrg3FfCd1u

If you are hiding `tr`, then use `display: table-row` instead of `display: block` to display that `tr`.

If you are hiding `td`, then use `display: table-cell` instead of `display: block` to display that `td`.

Use `table-row`, no `block` when styling a `tr`. Perfect!

Comment: Thanks Legionar..working nicely. also change `tabel` to `table` in your answer. lol

Comment: I added `display: block` to a `<TR>` to make `page-break-after: always;` work.  This of course rendered `colspan` useless.  Changing it to `display: table-row` fixed the colspan issue but didn't allow for the page break.  Not specific to this question, but I want to let you know this solution could have other consequences.