# Html table fixed column width

Tags: html

I have an html table with 2 columns and 2 rows. I want the columns to stay fixed. So for example,

Row1Text   Dropdown 
Row2Text   Textbox

Instead what is happening is the Dropwdown is shifting over. For example,

Row1Text                                                           Dropdown
Row2Text   Textbox

This is happening in IE 11 and Chrome Version 35.0.1916.153. However, it works fine in IE9.

Here is the code I am using: http://jsfiddle.net/RnSXA/

```
    .Text {
        width:600px;
    }

    function DropdownChange(value) {
        if (value == "2") {
            document.getElementById("Row2").style.display = "block";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("Row2").style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <th align="left" style="width: 15%">
                Row1:
            </th>
            <td style="width: 85%">
                <select onchange="DropdownChange(this.value)">
                      <option value="1">1</option>
                      <option value="2">2</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Row2" style="display:none;">
            <th align="left" style="width: 15%">
                Row2:
            </th>
            <td style="width: 85%">
                <input type="text" class="Text"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use 'display:table-row' instead of 'display:block'. This question is answered in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784298/td-colspan-not-working-for-tr-with-ids):

Answer (score 0):

Change your html structure to follow:

**html**

```
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <th align="left" style="width: 15%">
            Row1:
            <select onchange="DropdownChange(this.value)">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
        </th>
        <td style="width: 85%"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Row2" style="display:none;">
        <th align="left" style="width: 15%">
            Row2:
        </th>
        <td style="width: 85%">
            <input type="text" class="Text"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You have to move your `select` inside `<th>`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RnSXA/1/)

Comment: This works as I wanted. However, I am confused as to why the column width's from my code aren't fixed. I explicitly set the header column for both rows to a width of 15%.

Comment: Cause you set on text width 600px.